# Restore default sound levels

Tags: sound, volume-control

I changed my sound levels, but I prefer the stock settings that Ubuntu was installed with. Removing every `$HOME` folder to delete all possible config files (besides the Downloads, Documents, etc.) has not helped. I've read answers to similar questions as well and tried restarting.

What can I do?